# Adding multiple functions to onChange with react and react-mde

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-functional-component

I am using https://github.com/andrerpena/react-mde to try and set up an interactive help page for a site that I'm building. I got the markdown editor to work but the problem is, every time an edit is made it does not save the edit anywhere. Below is the relevant code for getting the markdown editor to work.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("**Hello world!!!**");
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = React.useState("preview");
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container">
      <ReactMde
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        selectedTab={selectedTab}
        onTabChange={setSelectedTab}
        generateMarkdownPreview={markdown =>
          Promise.resolve(converter.makeHtml(markdown))
        }
      />
    </div>
```

I am planning on fixing this issue by passing "value" to a separate function every time the user switches to the preview tab of the editor that saves what they currently have in the backend. The problem is I can't find a way to add a function to onTabChange. I also tried adding a function to onChange that would update the backend every time the value changed, but I could also not figure that out. I'm pretty new to react and I'm curious if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, or if anyone can think of a way to add a second function to one of these two calls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the details in points.

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions to handle onChange and onTabChange instead of directly calling a state change:

```
const handleChange = (value) => {
  // Update the state
  setValue(value);
  // Do something else with value
  ...
}

<ReactMde
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could(*should*) think more React-ly. In functional components you can use an effect to call a passed callback with the current value (or tab).

Example:

```
const onChangeValue = value => console.log('VALUE CHANGED:', value);
const onChangeTab = value => console.log('TAB CHANGED:', value);
```

Pass callbacks and use effect hook(s) to respond to the changes in state:

```
export default function App({ onChangeTab, onChangeValue }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("**Hello world!!!**");
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState("write");

  useEffect(() => {
    onChangeValue(value);
  }, [onChangeValue, value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    selectedTab === "preview" && onChangeTab(value);
  }, [onChangeTab, selectedTab, value]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ReactMde
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        selectedTab={selectedTab}
        onTabChange={setSelectedTab}
        generateMarkdownPreview={markdown =>
          Promise.resolve(converter.makeHtml(markdown))
        }
        loadSuggestions={loadSuggestions}
        childProps={{
          writeButton: {
            tabIndex: -1
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React-mde latest]